# ScaleTransform scales ContextMenu partially

Tags: c#, wpf

I got an application, where the whole window is scaling if a user resizes the window. This is the code to do this:

```
 ContentDesktop.LayoutTransform = new ScaleTransform(scale, scale);
```

Now I needed a Button with a ContextMenu, and this menu should scale like the application window. To do this, I bound the RenderTransform of the ContextMenu to the ScaleTransform of the Button:

```
  <Button.RenderTransform>
      <ScaleTransform ScaleX="{Binding ScaleFactor}" ScaleY="{Binding ScaleFactor}"/>
  </Button.RenderTransform>
  <Button.ContextMenu>
       <ContextMenu RenderTransform="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=PlacementTarget.RenderTransform}">
             <MenuItem Header="Item 1"/>
             <MenuItem Header="Item 2 wwww aaaa ssss iiii"/>
        </ContextMenu>
   </Button.ContextMenu>
```

The text of the MenuItems is now scaling, but for bigger ScaleFactors (>1.2) only a part of the ContextMenu is shown. The right and the bottom part are missing. As if someone cut it of.
But when I check the size (width, height), the ContextMenu is bigger as painted.

Someone got an idea what this could be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
<ContextMenu LayoutTransform="{Binding ...}">
```

**LayoutTransform**: A transform that's applied before the layout pass. So the `FrameworkElement` gets
rearranged in the greater scheme.

**RenderTransform**: A transform that's applied after the layout pass is completed. 
The `ContextMenu` spawns a new `Window`, but it's boundaries remain from before the transform and cut off the visual.